What type of variable would you classify $a, b, c$ etc shown in the picture? Would I just call them random, insignificant real values?

The variables don't really represent anything

Why do you think they are either random or insignificant?

they just represent any value I think, I don't know what I would call these variables.

I would call them “measurements”.

It is important to note that these are independent

a, b, and c might be a measured values where the measurement process isn't perfect. The measurements are tied to some physical features of the universe, but they are not exactly the right numbers.
If you repeated the measurements, you would get somewhat different numbers. The true value is in their somewhere. You would like to know how close your measurement is likely to be. You can take the mean to get the best estimate of the true value that your measurements can give. The standard deviation tells you about the spread. This tells you how close to the true value the average is likely to be.
Now you want to calculate a value related to your measurements. Perhaps a is the distance a moving object has traveled and b is the time it was traveling. Then a/b is the velocity. Given the uncertainties in a and b, what is the uncertainty of the velocity? The propagation of errors formulas can tell you this.
